# How to run a powershell script to generate exe in ubuntu with ps2exe package

Tags: scripts, windows, wine, executable, powershell

How to make powershell script to generate exe in ubuntu with ps2exe package.

**My script is working fine in Windows OS** but the same script not working in Ubuntu. I need to run this script in Ubuntu because I **have only one AWS cloud server which is working on Ubuntu OS.**
I have installed Powershell with the ps2exe extension in Ubuntu. but it not working fine.
I have no idea how to solve the following error and Is it possible to generate an exe file from a PowerShell script with ps2exe in Ubuntu ?

```
/home/mypc/.local/share/powershell/Modules/ps2exe/1.0.12/ps2exe.ps1:2762
Line |
2762 |      $cr = $cop.CompileAssemblyFromSource($cp, $programFrame)
     |      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Exception calling "CompileAssemblyFromSource" with "2" argument(s): "Operation is not supported on this platform."
Invoke-ps2exe: Output file /var/www/html/script/home/remote/aithentic-agent-win-installer.exe not written
```

Thanks